# Does CUDA have vector operation intrinsics?

Tags: cuda, simd, intrinsics

I thought that since CUDA can do 64-bit 128-bit load/store it might have some intrinsics for adding/subtracting/etc. vector types like float3, in fewer instructions like SSE.

Does CUDA have any such functions?

Comment: Depends on which level you are looking for vector operations (you mentioned intrinsics). Some 64-bit operations and vector operations, which can be directly used in C/C++ (like copying vector types or arithmetic operations on 64 bit types, but some more), are translated to 32-bit PTX/SASS instructions. (In the answers a few existing vector operations are mentioned.) In addition you could also call the Tensor Core somewhat a vector operation: On the one hand, it executes with one command several calculations per thread, on the other hand the whole warp is involved.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. Each thread (as of Kepler) can only run 1 single-precision floating point operation at a time, with the exception of the FMA - which can perform 1 multiplication and 1 addition in a single instruction (z = a*x + y).

Comment: Not quite true: There are some so called SIMD Video Instructions, operating on two 16 bit or four 8 bit words. If I remember right, they were introduced with Kepler, see also: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.2.pdf page 178

Comment: For ready-to-use wrapper functions for these "SIMD video instructions", check out: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/535684/announcements/release-1-1-of-simd-in-a-word-functions-posted/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these days, CUDA *does* have a few "vector operation intrinsics". At least, it does for half-precision floating point values.

Here's an example in PTX of the most obvious vector intrinsic: vectorized addition, with 2 half-precision floating-point values:

```ptx
// put some floats in half-precision registers
cvt.rn.f16.f32 h0, f0;
cvt.rn.f16.f32 h1, f1;
cvt.rn.f16.f32 h2, f2;
cvt.rn.f16.f32 h3, f3;

mov.b32  p1, {h0, h1};   // pack two f16 to 32bit f16x2
mov.b32  p2, {h2, h3};   // pack two f16 to 32bit f16x2
add.f16x2  p3, p1, p2;   // SIMD f16x2 addition
```

See the [relevant section of the PTX ISA guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#half-precision-floating-point-instructions-add).

Now, it's true that I've demonstrated this at the PTX level, but getting a proper C++ CUDA intrinsic is at most a matter of wrapping PTX-assembly instructions with an almost-one-liner function, if NVIDIA hasn't provided it already. See an example [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/blob/master/src/kat/on_device/ptx/video_instructions.cuh), for the "SIMD video instructions" mentioned by @kunzmi (it's part of my [cuda-kat](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/) library).

Comment: Those are PTX *instructions*.  The question asked for *intrinsics*, i.e. C function-like things which wrap them.  (Like Intel's `_tzcnt_u32(x)`, or sort of GNU C `__builtin_popcount(x)` to give examples of well-known intrinsics for either a specific asm instruction, or for an operation that many CPUs provide but which ISO C neglects to.)  It would be best to mention actual intrinsics, which I assume would take an `unsigned` or `int` arg, unless there's a typedef.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Like I said - the intrinsics are almost-one-liner wrappers around PTX instructions. Sometimes NVIDIA provides them, sometimes you write them yourself, like I have, for example, for the "video instructions", [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/blob/master/src/kat/on_device/ptx/video_instructions.cuh) in my cuda-kat library.